# How to draw an image on a canvas which then serves as background

Tags: canvas, javafx, nodes

I'm developing a game in javafx using tiles. My tiles are all in seperate .PNG files(16*16) which i then draw on a canvas. On a keystroke i want to move my character. Updating and redrawing the entire map takes too long and makes the game very choppy. (The map counts 50*40 tiles)

Is there a way to update a single node on the canvas ? Or is there a way for me to draw the character in an element that's on top of the canvas (the canvas serving as background) ?

Comment: Your question is really too broad. Some ideas: Maybe use different canvases for the background and the things that move (i.e. implement different layers, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/canvas.htm#JFXGR214). Or, just don't use a canvas at all, but use nodes placed in a pane.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reaction. I'm fairly new here, so I'm still trying to figure the format out.( I intentionally made my question broad, so it would be easy to find for people hitting on the same problem but I guess I was wrong. ) 
I've read using a canvas works faster then using a pane, that's why i'm working with a canvas. 
Reading trough the documents , I think it could be the solution to my problem. I always assumed when using two canvases the bottom one would be invisible. ( cause the canvas has a 100% opacity )